# Metrics for questions

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Lately I had a case that one of my questions was marked  **"as an exact duplicate".**

[Projection, rotation and skew-symetry in N-dimensional space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1779342/projection-and-rotation-in-n-dimensional-space)

[Commutativity of projection and rotation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778434/commutativity-of-projection-and-rotation)

But what the idea of "exactness" means regarding to questions?
The subjects of both questions were evidently different, and even if  they were really set in similar context, the two additional steps were required to go from one solution to the other - what was admitted by one of advocates for duplicativness.

**Maybe the number of  steps would be a good metrics for measuring distance between questions?

How can be measured distance between two questions in any other way?**

Comment: Related: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/18917/whither-the-duplicate

Comment: Note also [the dedicated thread for Requesting Reopening of Questions, etc.](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio).  Possibly the inclusion of words "skew symmetric" in your title would have discouraged some of those who voted to close as duplicate.

Comment: @hardmath So I included them.  All problem triggered my contemplation about the general nature of mathematical questions.  Maybe the class of "exact duplicate" is too narrow ? If labels of "approximate duplicate" and "question with tendency for duplication" were introduced the projected metrics on questions would be more objective.

Comment: By editing the Question's title you've suggested to me that you are still interested in an answer there.  In any case I've voted to reopen.

Comment: @hardmath  Of course question wasn't answered for all cases. Can be skew-symetric matrix decomposed somehow in higher dimensions involving rotation ? I don't know. Maybe it is possible but only for skew-symetric matrices with 3 DOF.